I have created a layout that inserts the user input directly to the database but the above code is not working
package com.example.recipeapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.recipeapp.databinding.ActivityAddRecipeBinding
import com.example.recipeapp.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class AddRecipeActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding: ActivityAddRecipeBinding by lazy{
        ActivityAddRecipeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_recipe)
        var db = Room.databaseBuilder(this@AddRecipeActivity, AppDatabase::class.java, "db_name")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .createFromAsset("recipe.db")
            .build()

        val daoObject: Dao = db.getDao()

        binding.addRecipe.setOnClickListener {
            val link = binding.recipeLink.text.toString()
            val recipeName = binding.recipename.text.toString()
            val recipeIng = binding.recipeIng1.text.toString()
            val recipeSteps = binding.recipeDes1.text.toString()
            val cat= binding.recipeCat1.text.toString()

            // Start the new activity after inserting the recipe
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                addRecipe(link, recipeName, recipeIng, recipeSteps, cat)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this@AddRecipeActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addRecipe(link: String, recipeName: String, recipeIng: String, recipeSteps: String, cat: String) {
        val recipe = Recipe(
            img = link,
            tittle = recipeName,
            des = recipeSteps,
            ing = recipeIng,
            category = cat
        )

        Dao.insertRecipe(recipe)
    }
}

I have created a Kotlin code that inserts data directly to the room database but the above code is not working I have stored the entered data in variables. Does the syntax for the above code is correct or do I need to modify it?
I want to modify the code so that the user entered data can directly inserts to the room database.

Here, you are inflating the binding incorrectly. Moreover, you are calling insertRecipe() on Dao directly, which should be done within the coroutine scope.
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.recipeapp.databinding.ActivityAddRecipeBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class AddRecipeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAddRecipeBinding
    private lateinit var daoObject: Dao

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAddRecipeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(this@AddRecipeActivity, AppDatabase::class.java, "db_name")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .createFromAsset("recipe.db")
            .build()

        daoObject = db.getDao()

        binding.addRecipe.setOnClickListener {
            val link = binding.recipeLink.text.toString()
            val recipeName = binding.recipename.text.toString()
            val recipeIng = binding.recipeIng1.text.toString()
            val recipeSteps = binding.recipeDes1.text.toString()
            val cat = binding.recipeCat1.text.toString()

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                addRecipe(link, recipeName, recipeIng, recipeSteps, cat)
                startActivity(Intent(this@AddRecipeActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun addRecipe(link: String, recipeName: String, recipeIng: String, recipeSteps: String, cat: String) {
        val recipe = Recipe(
            img = link,
            tittle = recipeName,
            des = recipeSteps,
            ing = recipeIng,
            category = cat
        )
        daoObject.insertRecipe(recipe)
    }
}

